# Matlab freezes when using plot function

Tags: opengl, matlab

Regardless of argument matlab freezes when a call a plotting related function.
When I use in matlab command-line `opengl info` the same error message as in this post is returned : [https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/316984-known-graphics-issues-with-skylake-intel-520-ubuntu](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/316984-known-graphics-issues-with-skylake-intel-520-ubuntu). 
I am using ubuntu 16.04 and i have the same graphics card as the guy from the post : skylake 520.

I have tried :

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132934
- starting from terminal with `matlab -softwareopengl`. This solves the problem actually, but i am searching for a more permanent way of fixing this.
  For example, how can include this setting in the startup file of matlab ?

Comment: Keep in mind that using software OpenGL makes the graphics look worse; read more at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#buwqyz8-6. I too have a problem with MATLAB freezing when plotting in Ubuntu 16.10 and my workaround is to prepend `LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1` in front of `matlab` in the terminal. Let me know if this works and I can write an answer. This is not a permanent solution though; a permanent solution probably needs to come from MATLAB (and I have already filed a bug report for this a while ago).

Comment: Can you expain what that line means ?

Comment: This is beyond my superficial knowledge of Mesa. What I do know is that it is an environment variable listed at http://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html and I saw this from https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1357571.

Comment: i have prepended it, but it still freezes. I will just stick to the -softwareopengl ''solution''. If you find another solution, i would be glad to hear it.